# How get woocommerce product price before and after save

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-hook

I want get and set log for woocommerce variation product price after product price change. (after click on update product)

EX :
Product 1 :
Variation 1 : old price : 10.000 , new price : 20.000
Variation 2 : old price : 30.000 , new price : 50.000

i test wp_insert_post_data filter and save_post_product action
but i can't get old price and two function return new price

How i can get product old price before new price saved in database

**die at the end of function for see result.

```
add_action('save_post_product', 'save_post_action', 10, 3);
function save_post_action( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
    if (get_post_type($post_id) !== 'product') return;
    $product = wc_get_product($post_id);
    $current_products = $product->get_children();
    foreach ($current_products as $variation_id) {
        $variable_product = wc_get_product($variation_id);
        //$regular_price = $variable_product->get_regular_price();
        //$sale_price = $variable_product->get_sale_price();
        $price = $variable_product->get_price();
        var_dump($price);
    }
    die;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable products are saved using Ajax before saving the parent.
So `woocommerce_admin_process_variation_object` action precedes save product variation.

```
add_action('woocommerce_admin_process_variation_object', 'get_previous_variation_price', 10, 1);
function get_previous_variation_price($variation) {
    $previous_price = $variation->get_price();
}
```